# Multiple Criteria, Multiple Outputs

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, countif

Trying to analyze criteria based on three scenarios to give me three different out puts

```
=ifs(COUNTIFs('ESU1'!A3:A50,"*DIRECT*",'ESU1'!B3:B50,"*CONSOLIDATION*",'ESU1'!C3:C50,">="&DATE(2011,10,1)),"On or After 10/01/2011"),COUNTIFS('ESU1'!A3:A50,"*DIRECT*",'ESU1'!B3:B50,"*CONSOLIDATION*",'ESU1'!C3:C50,"<"&DATE(2011,10,1)),"Before 10/01/2011"),"Needs to be Done")
```

I want to test  three criteria from 3 columns (all must be true) to give me one output "On or After 10/01/2011".  If those don't work test 3 more criteria across 3 columns (all must be true) and output "Before 10/01/2011", otherwise just put "Needs to be Done"

Comment: So what is the formula doing that is in error?

Comment: It is not executing stating that it is not a formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence is set up better for `IF` than `IFS`.
Try:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('ESU1'!A3:A50,"*DIRECT*",'ESU1'!B3:B50,"*CONSOLIDATION*",'ESU1'!C3:C50,">="&DATE(2011,10,1)),"On or After 10/01/2011",IF(COUNTIFS('ESU1'!A3:A50,"*DIRECT*",'ESU1'!B3:B50,"*CONSOLIDATION*",'ESU1'!C3:C50,"<"&DATE(2011,10,1)),"Before 10/01/2011","Needs to be Done"))
```